# Testing a 32-bit (or any "square" shaped) microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, prototyping

I know there are certain shaped microcontrollers that can fit onto a breadboard without using an actual PCB, like the Arduino. One can use normal jumper wires and utilize the breadboard to their own discretion with this type of microcontroller below.

[image: Breadboard with microcontroller and wires]

This is just a picture I found on the internet so I am not asking about how to configure a microcontroller on a breadboard.

Since there are different shapes of microcontrollers (particularly 32-bit or higher microcontrollers), there would be no easy way to test those types of microcontrollers.

[image: SMD microcontroller]

How would you be able to test these types of shaped microcontrollers? Obviously placing this on a breadboard could short circuit particular connections within the chip. Would we have to just place it on a PCB and then connect each pin with a jumper wire to connect it to a breadboard?

Comment: Carrier boards are an option for the smaller packages, especially if bypass caps are grafted on close to the package, but often some initial work is done with a manufacturer eval board, or else the designers have enough confidence (perhaps from past experience with the same or a similar chip) to go directly to a short-run PCB prototype.

Comment: Note the "shape" is called a **package**. The square ones are surface-mount packages (TQFP to be specific), they're much cheaper and easier for machines to solder. The big rectangle one is a through-hole package, specifically a DIP.

Comment: Usually to test out a component like that you would make a fully-fledged PCB for the prototype, and solder it on. There *are* services around to get custom PCBs cheaply. The component will also be rather cheap. Remember components are expendable - don't try to avoid soldering your microcontroller just because you'll need a new one if it doesn't work - instead, just get 10.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can buy adapter pcbs. Just solder the smd part on it, and pin headers on each side. Then you can just plug the assembly on a regular breadboard. I have a small stock of these boards for various shapes of smd parts. See the picture. [image]